# MongoDB and Node.js: saving int32 as double

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a variable defined in Node.js, for example

```
var foo = 15
```

I know JavaScript treat this value as a floating number and I can't specify the type.
I am using mongodb module to save this value into a document:

When I save the value with insert method and I pass the value to the method, I observe in my db document that the type is int32, but I need that mongodb save the value as double (15.0000).

It is possible to do so?

Comment: If strict typing is a requirement for your application then you should seriously reconsider your technology stack.

Comment: My example is simplified, the processes in place are more complex and the application is big (I need strict typing for this functionality and not for others). And I can't decide to change technology, I should find a solution in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### MongoDB likely only stores numerical values as doubles.

MongoDB uses [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html) which is a binary-encoded serialization of JSON-like documents, which are in turn, a subset of JavaScript object literals.  BSON does define "double" as well as "int32" and "int64" types; however, it is unclear if those integer types are usable directly by MongoDB drivers or if they are abstract types.

Looking at it another way; in JavaScript all numerical values are [Numbers](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.19) and Numbers are [IEEE 754 double precision 64-bit floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985).  Because of this fact, *JavaScript itself does not differentiate between integer and floating point types*.

To further understand how MongoDB itself handles numerical types you can play with the mongo shell:

```text
$ mongo foo
> db.foo.insert({looksLike:'int',   value:15})
> db.foo.insert({looksLike:'float', value:15.0})
> db.foo.insert({looksLike:'int64', value:Math.pow(2, 60)})
> db.foo.find({value:{ $type: 1 }}, {_id:0}) // Type 1 is "double".
{ "looksLike" : "int", "value" : 15 }
{ "looksLike" : "float", "value" : 15 }
{ "looksLike" : "int64", "value" : 1152921504606847000 } // Note inexact value.
```

As you can see, regardless of what numerical type one might expect to see, everything is stored as a double precision floating point value.

See also [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/6HNs8OLFYmQ).

Ultimately, if you must use MongoDB and if some database clients must handle numerical values with specific numerical types (e.g. int32, int64) then the client itself must perform the type conversion because MongoDB will not do it for you.

Comment: The client that extracts data from mongodb is written in visual basic and crashes when it finds integers..the log says something like "can't treat int32 as double"...I would avoid to put the hands in visual basic but maybe there is no other way...

Comment: Not true as you should use db.foo.insert({looksLike:'int', value:NumberInt(5)})

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can save it as double. But as indicated by @maerics type casting has to be done by you on Nodejs side. MongoDB won't do it for you.

For your solution:

```
var Double = require("mongodb").Double;
var foo = Double(15)
```

Now you can insert foo in a collection and you will see, it is there as double.

Comment: It works, but to be more clean:
const { ObjectId, $date, NumberInt, Int32, Double } = require('mongodb'); 
        people[i] = { ...people[i], "id": Double(Number(123546456))}; Double is important to add. You can add more feats with one line of code